# Json test returned data in LINQ form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, json, unit-testing

```
public JsonResult GetPayments()
        {
            var paymentTypes = PaymentRepository.GetAll();

            var jsonData = new { rows = paymentTypes.Select(q => new { Id = q.Id.ToString(), q.Name }).ToList() };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

It basically returns the `Id` and `Name` of the `Payments` as Json data.

I was wanting to test this so I was wanting to test that each row of data generated had the right information in it.

However the `JsonResult` returned I can do:

```
JsonResult.Data
```

I can't seem to get to the individual rows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989471/asp-net-mvc-how-to-unit-test-an-action-method-which-returns-jsonresult) a few months ago.

As the accepted answer states, i ended up using a simple reflection-based test helper to check the properties.

The alternative (answered after i accepted the original answer) is to make the internals of the web project visible to your tests project.