# Asserting JsonResult Containing Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, unit-testing

I was trying to unit test a method in one of my Controllers returning a JsonResult. To my surprise the following code didn't work:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test() {
    return Json(new {Id = 123});
}
```

This is how I test it (also note that the test code resides in another assembly):

```
// Act
dynamic jsonResult = testController.Test().Data;

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(123, jsonResult.Id);
```

The `Assert` throws an exception:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id'

I've since resolved it by using the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test() {
   dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
   data.Id = 123;
   return Json(data);
}
```

I'm trying to understand why isn't the first one working ? It also seems to be working with basically anything BUT an anonymous type.

Comment: I tried your code with the anonymous type and it worked fine for me.  Not sure why you're getting that error.

Comment: What do you get when you print out `jsonResult.GetType()`?  (the error indicates it thinks it's of type `object` rather than of type `<>f__AnonymousType0`, which is what I'd expect)

Comment: The type is object indeed. I expected it to work myself, not sure why I'm getting those results.

Comment: This short snippet works fine for me:  `var result = new JsonResult { Data = new { Id = "foo" } }; dynamic foo = result.Data; Console.WriteLine(foo.Id);`  Does it work for you?

Comment: @KirkWoll, thanks for your help, mate, It appears that anonymous can't be used in other libraries (check out LukLed's answer), I didn't know this, gonna read some more.

Comment: @KirkWoll and, yes by the way it does work (when I place it in the Unit Tests project), however as soon as I place it in Production and access it from the Unit Test project -> it fails. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unit test an Action method which returns JsonResult?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989471/how-to-unit-test-an-action-method-which-returns-jsonresult)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To be clear, the specific problem you are encountering is that C# dynamic does not work with non-public members.  This is by design, presumably to discourage that sort of thing.  Since as LukLed stated, anonymous types are public only within the same assembly (or to be more precise, anonymous types are simply marked `internal`, not `public`), you are running into this barrier.

Probably the cleanest solution would be for you to use `InternalsVisibleTo`.  It allows you to name another assembly that can access its non-public members.  Using it for tests is one of the primary reasons for its existance.  In your example, you would place in your primary project's AssemblyInfo.cs the following line:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyNameOfYourTestProject")]
```

Once you do that, the error will go away (I just tried it myself).

Alternatively, you could have just used brute force reflection:

```
Assert.AreEqual(123, jsonResult.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(jsonResult, null));
```

Comment: Can you explain the last option ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you wondering about reflection in general or something about how it applies to this question/answer?

Comment: reflection in general

Comment: @Ani, in that case, I think that is too big a topic to discuss in comments and such elaboration would, I believe, be distracting from the OP's original question.  The essential gist here is that you can get the `PropertyInfo` from a `Type` and using it can get or set the value of the property, regardless of whether or not the type is internal by using the `GetValue` method.

Answer (score 15):

Having read the responses here and then looking further afield I found a [2009 msdn blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/25/unit-testing-the-mvc-jsonresult.aspx) with a different approach again. But.. in the comments was a very simple and very elegant solution by [Kieran](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/25/unit-testing-the-mvc-jsonresult.aspx#9981186) ... to use `.ToString()`.

In your original case:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json(new {Id = 123});
}
```

You could test by doing:

```
var jsonResult = controller.Test();
Assert.AreEqual("{Id = 123}", jsonResult.Data.ToString());
```

I much prefer this solution as it:

- avoids changing the original code (`InternalsVisibleTo`, `ExpandoObject`),
- avoids using **MvcContrib** and **RhinoMocks** (no issue with either of these but why add just to be able to test `JsonResult`?), and,
- avoids using **Reflection** (adds complexity to the tests).

Comment: This relies on the ToString implementation not changing, - 1

Answer (score 5):

Anonymous types are internal, so you can't expose them to another library, the one with tests. If you placed testing code in the same library as controller, it will work.

Comment: You could also declare the testing assembly a "friend assembly" in order to expose internals.   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.80).aspx